# How can I troubleshoot a raw mssql query that runs fine on SQL Server but fails in Laravel?

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

I am running raw queries to MS SQL Server in laravel. The query works fine when parsed in SQL Server, however when I run it in Laravel to return it to a view, I am getting the error message

```
Check messages from the SQL Server [207] (severity 16) [(null)]
```

When I query the general error 207, I find

```
Invalid column name '%.*ls'.
```

The query is as follows:

```
SELECT :term AS TERM_REPORTING, AG.AGE_GROUP, COALESCE(TB.usercount, 0) AS usercount
FROM (
    SELECT TERM_REPORTING, MY_AGE_GROUP, SUM(ID_COUNT) as usercount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Level_grouping_desc like '%Undergraduate' THEN ID_Count ELSE 0 END) as Undergraduate, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Level_grouping_desc ='2. Graduate' then ID_Count ELSE 0 END) as Graduate, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Level_grouping_desc like '%Professional' THEN ID_Count ELSE 0 END) as Professional
    FROM Student_Enrollment_agcl
    WHERE TERM_REPORTING = :term
    AND PRIMARY_COLLEGE_CODE = :college_code
    GROUP BY TERM_REPORTING, MY_AGE_GROUP
    ) AS TB
RIGHT JOIN Student_Enrollment_Age_Groups AG ON TB.MY_AGE_GROUP = AG.AGE_GROUP
```

I appreciate any help anyone can offer as I'm not even sure where I should begin troubleshooting an issue like this.

And sorry, yes, I am trying to write these queries in the raw rather than using eloquent because I am trying to maintain conventions set by a previous developer for the sake of readability for some of my coworkers unfamiliar with eloquent.

In laravel, I use:

```
$graphData = DB::connection('sqlsrv')->select(DB::raw("
SELECT :term AS TERM_REPORTING, AG.AGE_GROUP, COALESCE(TB.usercount, 0) AS usercount
FROM (
    SELECT TERM_REPORTING, MY_AGE_GROUP, SUM(ID_COUNT) as usercount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Level_grouping_desc like '%Undergraduate' THEN ID_Count ELSE 0 END) as Undergraduate, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Level_grouping_desc ='2. Graduate' then ID_Count ELSE 0 END) as Graduate, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Level_grouping_desc like '%Professional' THEN ID_Count ELSE 0 END) as Professional
    FROM Student_Enrollment_Age_grp_Class_level
    WHERE TERM_REPORTING = :term
    AND PRIMARY_COLLEGE_CODE = :college_code
    GROUP BY TERM_REPORTING, MY_AGE_GROUP
) AS TB
RIGHT JOIN Student_Enrollment_Age_Groups AG ON TB.MY_AGE_GROUP = AG.AGE_GROUP
"), ['term' => $term, 'college_code' => $college]);
```

Not sure if it matters but I enabled MSSQL support by installing php5-sybase and configuring the connection in the database config for laravel.

Comment: Post what you have done so far and the errors you are getting

Comment: I posted what I have done and the errors I received in my original question. Are you looking for something more specific?

Comment: Maybe try to install barryvdh's debug bar https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar and check that your sqlquery look like what you are looking for. I assume you've already checked that db connection is ok.

Comment: Yeah, I've got the debugbar running and really all it tells me is that the query never gets run because of the error.